# How do changes to the IIS metabase effect running applications?

Tags: iis

What I need to know is if adding custom classes and properties to the IIS metabase schema will cause any running app pools to restart or sessions to be killed off?

Comment: You should consider taking this question to Server Fault http://serverfault.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familer with any metabase changes that cause application pool to recycle.